# Access uploaded file in shiny in other abc.r files except server.r

Tags: r, file, shiny

In my server.r I am reading uploaded file using

```
  dat <- reactive({
          if (is.null(input$datafile1$datapath))
             {
                dat <- read.csv("D:/sample_withbatch.csv")

                read.csv("D:/sample_withbatch.csv")
                x<<-dat



                } else {
                dat <- read.csv(input$datafile1$datapath)

                read.csv(input$datafile1$datapath)
                x<<-dat

                }

  })
```

Using dat() I can access the uploaded file.

Now I want some other program like abc.r should also automatically update 
the dataframe named df.data with the contents of the uploaded file and plot the graphs in shiny.
I have this code in global.r:

```
source("abc.R",local = TRUE)
```

Its not working.

Comment: Why do you want some other program to use the data that you got here? Why not do the plotting in this app itself?

Comment: ok.The code is too big and thats why i want to use it in other program.Thanks

Comment: Shiny is not designed for data transfer usually. If you are taking the file as input from the user, you can save the file on disk and then use it as an input in your other code `abc.R` for plotting. But then, would it not make more sense to use `abc.R` itself for getting the file and then plotting it?

Comment: abc.r has only r code .ui and server. r has shiny code.I even tried to read the file in server.r and then save it on disk and read it in abc.r but still its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      tableOutput("contents")        
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$file1) # require that input is available, prevents error when no data uploaded
    inFile <- input$file1
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    return(df)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dat()["name.of.column"])
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    dat()
  })

}
```

You can upload the data using `read.csv(inFile$datapath)` and access it by making it a reactive value as you have done. Also, make sure you place your ui.R and server.R in the same directory and run your app using `runApp("your_directory_path")`

Comment: Thanks,But here you are plotting in server.r . I want to export dat() in other program like abc.r & access data frame there to plot the data.

Comment: I have ui.r,server.r,global.r and abc.r.In abc. r I do some calculation to plot the graphs.I plot those graphs in server.r

Comment: I don't think its possible to do things that way. Since dat() is a reactive dataframe, I'd suggest do your calculations/plotting in server.R itself.